# How to create a Homebrew Monk Ki feature using DnD Beyond?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, monk, homebrew, dnd-beyond

I am trying to create a Homebrew, Ki fueled feature for a Monk. I would like to use DnD Beyond to create the feature and store it for my campaign. However, I can only see templates which lead me through creating a spell or a feat. Is there any way to create a Ki based monk feature?

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, you cannot create your own class features in D&D Beyond. You have to create a custom class. Just copy the monk class and add your feature.